# How to retrieve values from created textboxes using for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have created textboxes in javascript using for loop with this code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.setAttribute('id', "di" + i);
    document.getElementById('t').appendChild(div1)

    var tx = document.createElement('input');
    tx.setAttribute('id', i);

    var di = document.getElementById("di" + i);

    di.appendChild(tx);
    var br = document.createElement('br');
    di.appendChild(br);
    tx.onblur = (function (i) {
        return function (evt) {
            num = Number(evt.currentTarget.value);
            var currentId = evt.currentTarget.id;
            var d = document.getElementById('di' + i);
            for (x = 0; x < num; x++) {
                var b = document.createElement('b');
                b.innerHTML = "num" + (x + 1);
                var tx1 = document.createElement('input');
                tx1.setAttribute('id', 'tx' + x);
                d.appendChild(br);
                d.appendChild(b);
                d.appendChild(tx1);
                d.appendChild(br);
            }
        }
    })(i);
    di.appendChild(br);
}
```

I create a button onclick function i want to retrieve the values of each num in this format: (num1+num2+num3) for each textbox of the three textboxes each one in different line..

```
var sub = document.getElementById('sub');
sub.onclick = function () {
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cv1 = document.getElementById("tx" + i).value;
        cc += cv1 + "+";
    }
    document.write("(" + cc + ")" + "<br>");
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I am finally figured what required and deleted my previous answer. This is the new one

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.setAttribute('id', "di" + i);
    document.getElementById('t').appendChild(div1)

    var tx = document.createElement('input');
    tx.id = "txt" + i;

    var di = document.getElementById("di" + i);
    di.appendChild(tx);

    var br = document.createElement('br');
    di.appendChild(br);

    tx.onblur = (function (item) {
        return function (evt) {
            num = Number(evt.currentTarget.value);
            var d = document.getElementById('di' + item);
            for (var x = 0; x < num; x++) {
                var b = document.createElement('b');
                b.innerHTML = "num" + (x + 1) + " ";
                var tx1 = document.createElement('input');
                tx1.setAttribute('id', item + 'tx' + x);
                d.appendChild(br);
                d.appendChild(b);
                d.appendChild(tx1);
                d.appendChild(br);
            }
        }
    })(i);
    di.appendChild(br);
}

function show() {
    var cc = "";
    for (var m = 0; m < 3; m++) {
        cc += "(";
        var element = document.getElementById("txt" + m);
        var count = Number(document.getElementById("txt" + m).value);
        if (count > 0) {
            for (var b = 0; b < count; b++) {
                if (b > 0) cc += "+";
                cc += document.getElementById(m + "tx" + b).value;
            }
        }
        cc += ")<br/>";
    }
    document.write(cc);
}
```

your code has several problems

1. When you give id to sub input field it is "tx" + some x index but it can be more than one field with same name, you should give a unique name.

2. onclick function looping until i < 3 but it can be less than 3 fields cause number of fields depended on number entered in "parent" field.

Posted code should to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

actually after executing this script your generated `HTML` would be

[image]

so your generated text fields has the `ids` equals to 0,1,2 but in your code you r fetching values with something `tx0` , `tx1` , `tx2` so there is no components with these ids so just tweak your `onclick` function as

```
 sub = document.getElementById('sub');
cc = "";
        sub.onclick = function () {
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                cv1 = document.getElementById( i).value;
                cc += cv1 + "<br/>";
            }
            document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = cc;
        };
```

and it will work fine [here](http://jsbin.com/xexaborizi/1/) is bin of working example :)

Comment: when i enter a number in the three textboxes more text boxes will be created for each, the ids of it will be tx0, tx1,tx2 ... it is created in the first code. 
                var tx1 = document.createElement('input');
                tx1.setAttribute('id', 'tx' + x);